# Why my cup's uv unwrapping is not like this?

Tags: uv

After i unwrap my cup, the uv mapping is looks like this[image]

But Blender Guru's one is split half perfectly just like this [image]

Why is this happening? Is it because of wrong placement of mark seam?

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here https://blend-exchange.com/b/z0PG5Ea2, i dont know why pasteall.org is error

Comment: once you've unwrapped, in the Operator box, try Conformal instead of Angle Based?

Comment: it worked!, I have tried it and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've unwrapped, in the *Operator* box, choose *Conformal* instead of *Angle Based*:

[image]